# Remove trailing zeros and use 6 decimal points in Matlab

Tags: matlab, printing, printf

I wish to utilize som sort of combination of %f and %g in my fprintf. I wish to remove trailing zeros and use 6 decimal points if there are 6 decimals that are non zero. %g removes zeros but here precision does not affect the number of decimal points. What to do?

Comment: Please add examples to your questions (test cases)

Answer (score 3):

So if this is the behaviour you want:

0.123456789 -> 0.123457 (rounded up at the 6th decimal place)

999.123456789 -> 999.123457 (six decimal places, regardless of the number of significant figures)

1.123000000 -> 1.123 (remove trailing zeros)

then you can use %f:

```
fprintf('%.6f', number);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%.<n>g`, where n defines maximal number of digits to be used.

```
>> fprintf('%.6g\n', 4087.145678);
4087.15

>> fprintf('%.6g\n', 45.2);
45.2
```